# Execute R code before and after each code chunk in a quarto document?

Tags: r, quarto

For timing measurements, I would like to execute before each code block the function `tic()` and after `toc()` from the package [tictoc](http://jabiru.github.io/tictoc/). As I have many code blocks, I was wondering if I could define this in the beginning of the quarto document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`chunk-hooks`](https://yihui.org/knitr/hooks/#chunk-hooks) exactly does what you want. From the docs,

> Chunk hooks are functions to be called before or after a code chunk when the chunk option is not NULL

````
---
title: "Code Chunk Timing"
format: html
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| echo: false

library(tictoc)

knitr::knit_hooks$set(timeit = function(before, options, envir) {
    if(before) {
      ## code to be run before a chunk
      tic()
    } else {
      ## code to be run after a chunk
      elapsed = toc()$toc
      print(paste0("Execution took ", elapsed, " seconds"))
    }
})

```

```{r}
#| timeit: true

sum = 0
for (i in 1:1000) sum = sum + 1
```
````

---

[image: timing the code chunks]

Comment: Also see the `hooktime` function in the `qreport` package.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, got interested and just installed `qreport` and can't find `hooktime()`. Can't find it through rdrr.io either. Where is it?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Forgot I need to update CRAN which I'll do in several days.  In the mean time run `source('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/harrelfe/qreport/master/R/reptools.r')` to get `hooktime`.